# Regular expression for double equals

Tags: .net, regex

Anyone have a good regex to match `==` and `!=` but NOT `===` nor `!==` (I'm planning to use it as a simple check on javascript code)?

I tried `[^=]==[^=]` but this fails at the start and end of strings.

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would `==` ever occur at the beginning/end of a to-be-checked string?

Comment: @Sniffer - probably C# but maybe also TypeScript/JS.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Example: `a =={new line}b`. That happens a fair amount in code if you try to stick to rational line length limits.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - I just wanted a robust expression! Also if I parse it line-by-line, == could be on one line and the operand on the next

Comment: Why not simply `[!=]=([^=]|$)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your regex engine fully supports [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (e.g., .NET), then use

```
(?<![!=])[!=]=(?!=)
```

If not (JavaScript!), you need to handle the character before the match explicitly:

```
(?:^|[^!=])([!=]=)(?!=)
```

Comment: Should this work in .NET 4? If I try it on "!==" It matches at location 1 (matching "==")

Comment: @user826840: Oh, you're right! Now it should work correctly. (It also rejects `!!=`, but I suppose that's OK, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Try use the following:

```
[^=!]([=!]=)[^=]
```

http://rubular.com/r/Db8fv6RQht